# Google Combo Chart + multiple legend for != data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

a short explenation.

I'm using a google Combo chart to display the graph below :https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#Configuration_Options

But, as you can see, it's not easy to read blue values, as long as the red line is the accumulate of blue values, it can go very high. 
[image: The picture i have currently.]
Is there a way to put a second legend on the right of the picture? In order to the red line to stay at a reasonable high, and make all this thing readable easely? i read the doc about legend, but i didn't found:

how to put a second legend ? 
How to make the red line folow the second legend?
just in case. Do you have some snippet ?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple vAxes and specify which series is plotted on which axis.
Roughly something like:

```
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Just data, use your own
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Value', 'Cumulate'],
      ['2014/01/01',  5,   5],
      ['2014/01/02', 20,  25],
      ['2014/01/03',  7,  32],
      ['2014/01/04', 15,  47],
      ['2014/01/05',  3,  50],
      ['2014/01/06',  5,  55],
      ['2014/01/07',  0,  55],
      ['2014/01/08',  0,  55],
      ['2014/01/09', 10,  65],
      ['2014/01/10',  5,  70],
      ['2014/01/11', 10,  80],
      ['2014/01/12',  0,  80],
      ['2014/01/13',  7,  87],
      ['2014/01/14', 13,  90],
      ['2014/01/15', 10, 100]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Pluviometre',
      // multiple axis (you can have different labels, colors, etc.)
      vAxes: [
        {title: "mm/h"},
        {title: "mm/h",textStyle:{color: "red"}}
      ],
      hAxis: {title: "date"},
      seriesType: "bars",
      // 1st series on axis 0 (by default), 2nd series on axis 1
      series: {1: {type: "line", targetAxisIndex:1}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```